# No binding Value Property of Slider in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I'm new to programming in Windows Phone 8. I am studying "The Binding". I try to bind the property "Value" of a Slider, but when running the application I do not see any change.

The XAML code is this:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <StackPanel>
        <Slider Minimum="1" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Valor}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The ViewModelBase class is this:

```
public class VMBase : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public VMBase() {}

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName) {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
}
```

The ViewModel class is this:

```
public class VMSlider : VMBase {
    private int _valor;

    public VMSlider() {
        _valor = 43;
    }

    public int Valor {
        get { return _valor; }
        set { 
            _valor = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Valor");
        }
    }
}
```

In the code-behind class of my XAML y write this:

```
this.DataContext = new ViewModel.VMSlider();
```

I need to say why.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you get binding errors in the 'Output' window of Visual Studio when running with the debugger attached?

Comment: When you say "you don't see any change", what are you inspecting that doesn't change? Are you setting Valor from the code and expecting the slider to change, or vice-versa?

Comment: Also, depending on when you're newing up VMSlider, you may want to set _valor using the public setter in the constructor for VMSlider, that way the property change notification fires (in case the binding is already set up at that point).

Comment: It is a rare case. When I remove the property [Minimun = "1"] and run the application, the slider appears with the value 43, otherwise not. Also, if I add the property [Mode = TwoWay] (with Minimun) works. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Value property on the Slider control is of type [Double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase.value%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Your Binding doesn't work because Valor is a value of the wrong type.

You must either implement a [Value Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or `change Valor to a Double`.